# If A implies B and B is not a tautology, then the negation of A also implies B?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I wanted to ask you if the following claim is correct, assuming the principle of bivalence:

"If $B$ is not a tautology and $A \models B$, then $ \lnot A \not\models B$"

My reasoning is the following, indicating Models of $A, B$ with $Ma,Mb$ and with $Ca$ the countermodels of $A$.

if $A \models B$, then $Ma \subseteq Mb$;
B is not a tautology, so there is a valutation in which it is false.

Supposing that $ \lnot A \models B$, then $Ca \subseteq Mb$.

Since $Ca \cup Ma$ are all the possibile valutations of the language, and are all models of $B$, $B$ must be a tautology. But this contradicts the assumption.

Is the proof correct?